# XPath : check if first child is desired or not

Tags: xpath

I want to check if the first child is `B` or not in the following code:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C> 123</C>
  </B>
</A>
<A>
  <E>
    <C> 00</C>
  </E>
  <B>
    <C>121</C> 
  </B>
</A>
```

Here there are two `A` and in both we have `B`. I want to check if first child of `A` is `B` and print value in `C` in it.
How can I do this. using xpath?

Comment: How did you try. Show your current XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
//A/*[1][self::B]/C
```

It gets the first child element of `A` node that is a `B` node, then gets its `C` node content.

Answer (score 0):

Use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
A[child::*[1] = child::B]/B[1]/C
```

It checks if the first child node of `A` is identical with the first `B` child node. If yes, then it selects the first `B` node and returns the value of its `C` child.